# using linebreaks to optimize html page load

Tags: html, performance, page-load-time

Please find the code given below:

```
<img src="test1.jpg" width=50%/>
<img src="test2.jpg" width=50%/>
<img src="test3.jpg" width=50%/>
<img src="test4.jpg" width=50%/>
```

Will the  **performance** be improved if I include linebreaks in the relevant places? (as below):

```
<img src="test1.jpg" width=50%/>
<img src="test2.jpg" width=50%/>          <br/>
<img src="test3.jpg" width=50%/>
<img src="test4.jpg" width=50%/>
```

Comment: Most likely not. But the size of the images matter. Correct sized images load quicker than larger sized images that has to be shrunk in size to fit

Comment: @Andreas, good point, but how would you do that when using percentages to get a responsive design?

Comment: @user1930608 providing resources at different resolutions (picking right one with JavaScript or using in CSS `background-image` (sigh) or `content: url(...)` with media queries

Comment: I don't think that putting `<br />` linebreaks will make the page load faster.
Page speed relies not only on HTML but also the assets you load, XMLHttp Request you do, etc. that makes up the entire webpage.

Comment: If you are loading alot of images, just make sure it is optimized. you can refer to alot of tools to optimize the filesize of your images like https://tinypng.com/ or https://tinyjpg.com/. You can also use image preloaders, so at first you only show few images and load the other images as background process

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in response User1930608. I can't give you a optimum image size, but if you look at your users on the page, what screen size do they use? Maybe a lower resolution will not make the image look 'that bad', so if you shrink the image and then let the browser enlarge it. May work. I don't know. But you seem to have an issue with loading time (hence the question), I'm just giving you some ideas. It's not a solution or answer.

Comment: @Andreas the issue is that the images should be as small as reasonable, or that the browser should be able to display the image without "working"?

Comment: Your images require the `alt` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When HTML page is loaded in browser, all elements are displayed in floated style, if second image width is larger than maximum page width, it will be displayed below first image, this is managed by browser internally. What does matters here is how much byte size your image is, because page load means transfer of data between server and client.

Comment: so the issue is the byte size, or whether the browser has to "work" to display the image?  In other words, is making the browser enlarge the image the same going to give the same speed as giving the right size image to begin with, or be faster?

Comment: I have no proof of this, but I think.... If network speed is the problem (mobil phones) it's better to have a small image that the browser enlarges/scales up. If we are talking about computers with good network, then none of it should be an issue ( not an issue to download large images, and not an issue to scale up an image). Computers have enough CPU to resize an image, and most phones too. So as I see it, the lag is most likely the time to download the image.

Comment: Page Load is not only "transfer of data between server and client".  It also includes rendering.  There is a page load time for the loading of the base HTML but that is when the loading of CSS then rendering begins.  Then there is the time to load all the resources like images.  Then there is Visually Complete and Fully Loaded.

Answer (score 2):

### YES

I did not think it would have any affect, but it did.

### But in your case probably NO.

I benchmark all sorts of page load scenarios., one of them being images without width and height. Where the HTML looks like this:

```
elseif(intval($_GET['rev']) == 5){ 
echo<<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head><title>img no wxh</title><style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body><div>
<img  alt="image 00001" src="Image00001.jpg"/>
<img  alt="image 00002" src="Image00002.jpg"/>
<img  alt="image 00003" src="Image00003.jpg"/>
<img  alt="image 00004" src="Image00004.jpg"/>
...
<img  alt="image 00055" src="Image00055.jpg"/>
<img  alt="image 00056" src="Image00056.jpg"/>
<img  alt="image 00057" src="Image00057.jpg"/>
<img  alt="image 00058" src="Image00058.jpg"/>
</div></body></html>
EOT;
```

I copied that test and added `<br/>` after each image.

```
elseif(intval($_GET['rev']) == 6){ 
echo<<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>base64</title><style type="text/css"></style></head><body><div>
<img  alt="image 00001" src="Image00001.jpg"/><br/>
<img  alt="image 00002" src="Image00002.jpg"/><br/>
<img  alt="image 00003" src="Image00003.jpg"/><br/>
<img  alt="image 00004" src="Image00004.jpg"/><br/>
...
<img  alt="image 00055" src="Image00055.jpg"/><br/>
<img  alt="image 00056" src="Image00056.jpg"/><br/>
<img  alt="image 00057" src="Image00057.jpg"/><br/>
<img  alt="image 00058" src="Image00058.jpg"/><br/>
</div></body></html>
EOT;
```

I ran each scenario two times. Tested with Google Chrome Browser.

**FIRST RUN NO BREAKS**

```
TTFB    200 mS
DOM Loaded  326 mS
First Paint 791 mS
Start Render    985 mS
Load Time   2,074 mS
Rendering   1,198 mS
Fully Loaded    2,240 mS
Visual Complete 2,183 mS
```

**SECOND RUN NO BREAKS**

```
TTFB    277 mS
DOM Loaded  358 mS
First Paint 656 mS
Start Render    692 mS
Load Time   2,138 mS
Rendering   1,500 mS
Fully Loaded    2,221 mS
Visual Complete 2,192 mS
```

---

### WITH Line Breaks

**Faster Page Rendering** and 
**Visually Complete was much sooner.**

**FIRST RUN WITH BREAKS**

```
TTFB    220 mS
DOM Loaded  377 mS
First Paint 894 mS
Start Render    991 mS
Load Time   2,263 mS
Rendering   199 mS
Fully Loaded    2,426 mS
Visual Complete 1,190 mS
```

**SECOND RUN WITH BREAKS**

```
TTFB    206 mS
DOM Loaded  355 mS
First Paint 866 mS
Start Render    889 mS
Load Time   2,267 mS
Rendering   399 mS
Fully Loaded    2,422 mS
Visual Complete 1,288 mS
```

### The question I had was Why?

The answer is in the difference between Visually Complete and Fully Loaded.

This is why Google is so concerned about "above the fold content" in Page Speed Insights.

These images were small as shown here with width and height:

```
<img width="90" height="90" alt="image 00001" src="Image00001.jpg"/>
<img width="120" height="79" alt="image 00002" src="Image00002.jpg"/>
<img width="112" height="90" alt="image 00003" src="Image00003.jpg"/>
<img width="111" height="90" alt="image 00004" src="Image00004.jpg"/>
<img width="75" height="90" alt="image 00005" src="Image00005.jpg"/>
<img width="92" height="90" alt="image 00006" src="Image00006.jpg"/>
<img width="90" height="90" alt="image 00007" src="Image00007.jpg"/>
<img width="112" height="90" alt="image 00008" src="Image00008.jpg"/>
<img width="118" height="90" alt="image 00009" src="Image00009.jpg"/>
```

**Without the line breaks every image was visible "above the fold"**

### Why will this not work for you?

A width of 50% will likely render the same as if there was a line break after each image. 50% does not allow two images to be side by side because the small space between the images which take the horizontal over 100%.

If the CSS removed the right and left  margins and the images did not have the actual line feed they might render two side by side. Or if the width were 49%

This HTML will convert the line feed to a space between the images:

```
<img src="test1.jpg" width=50%/>
<img src="test2.jpg" width=50%/>
```

No space between

```
<img src="test1.jpg" width=50%/><img src="test2.jpg" width=50%/>
```

Or if the width were 49%

```
<img src="test1.jpg" width=49%/>
<img src="test2.jpg" width=49%/>
```

Plus large images will fill the above the fold faster than small images.

### First paint vs. Start Rendering

First Paint layout the "wire frame".  In my test scenario with width and height  the first paint layout the images and the box they image will occupy.  I can actually see the alt text in the boxes.

Without the width and height First Paint does not know the size of the image so it cannot save the space required in the wire frame boxes.

The rendering must rearrange everything as each image is retrieved.

### UPDATE

I added a width="50%" to every image in both scenarios.

**No Line Break**

`<img width="50%"  alt="image 00001" src="Image00001.jpg"/>`

```
TTFB    211 mS
DOM Loaded  365 mS
First Paint 1,022 mS
Start Render    1,091 mS
Load Time   2,319 mS
Rendering   0 mS
Fully Loaded    2,494 mS
Visual Complete 1,091 mS
```

-

```
TTFB    203 mS
DOM Loaded  256 mS
First Paint 546 mS
Start Render    594 mS
Load Time   1,838 mS
Rendering   0 mS
Fully Loaded    1,987 mS
Visual Complete 594 mS
```

**WITH line breaks**

`<img width="50%"  alt="image 00001" src="Image00001.jpg"/><br/>`

```
TTFB    256 mS
DOM Loaded  352 mS
First Paint 740 mS
Start Render    793 mS
Load Time   2,110 mS
Rendering   0 mS
Fully Loaded    2,260 mS
Visual Complete 793 mS
```

-

```
TTFB    200 mS
DOM Loaded  285 mS
First Paint 653 mS
Start Render    691 mS
Load Time   1,978 mS
Rendering   0 mS
Fully Loaded    2,132 mS
Visual Complete 691 mS
```

### UPDATE TWO

Regarding your comment about the 50% and side by side I tested in

```
Chrome
FireFox
Safari
Opera
IE 8
```

And the results were just as I predicted., not side by side.  I change the code like this:

```
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00001" src="Image00001.jpg"/><img width="50%"  alt="image 00002" src="Image00002.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00003" src="Image00003.jpg"/><img width="50%"  alt="image 00004" src="Image00004.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00005" src="Image00005.jpg"/><img width="50%"  alt="image 00006" src="Image00006.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00007" src="Image00007.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00009" src="Image00009.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00011" src="Image00011.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00012" src="Image00012.jpg"/>
<img width="50%"  alt="image 00013" src="Image00013.jpg"/>
```

I also tried it with and without the div surrounding the images.

In all five Browsers, the page renders like this:

[image]

Comment: the width is actually 50% and they do show side by side. Are you saying that it is in fact preferable to put in the line breaks? (assume that the res is as low as I can allow it to get)

Comment: No, the reduced time to Visually Complete in my test  was due to the small size of the images.  In your case the line breaks will not change the above the fold (visual content) rendering.

Comment: The rendering time in your case is likely devoted mostly to re-scaling the images.  In my case all 58 images were above the fold visual content until I added the line breaks.

Comment: In that case this did not answer my question. (maybe I wasn't clear?) I was specifically talking about a case where the page will visually render the same in either case

Comment: I answered it will in some cases but not very likely in you case with large images.  The answer for you is NO.  Originally after seeing my test results I thought it would help. It was not until I discovered why as I was writing up my results that I knew it would not help you.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer but my only query would be that running the different scenarios  only twice each seems somewhat small number of test runs, although the difference is relatively huge (~40%+), test runs of 5 or 10 would/could give even more concrete statistical results, but still, a very interesting answer. +1

Comment: Knock yourself out, I posted my code.  I've been doing page speed optimization for over five years.  I understand this stuff down to the modular level.  By looking at the results in each scenario I was able to see the difference and why.  I did run more tests than I posted. Yes statically more test are better.  Common sense tells me the results will be the same.  In the update I did not run too many more.  The differences were due to the image load times, not the HTML.  The waterfall images are too large to post.  I gave your question a +1 a while back.

Comment: I test the 50% side by side theory and made an update with the results.